# iOS Child Views, SRP and custom events

Tags: objective-c, events, ios5, view, single-responsibility-principle

I'm kind of new to iOS development and need some advice. I have a chat like app. The UI should have a child view for posting new messages to the server and one child view for viewing messages in a table view.

I've build both child views in Interface Builder as XIB:s. But I'm not sure how to use these on the main view controller. Can I use IB to add my custom views to the design surface? Or do I need to add these programmatically?

What is the best way to send messages or custom events between these two child views? I'd like to have them as decoupled as possible. Mostly I'd like to send an event when the user log on or off, so that the UI can react to these changes. I'd also like the table view with messages to know when a new messages is posted from the write view.

// Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the contents of a xib file you've got to load it first sending `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` message to NSBundle class.

Consider you have a UIView subclass named CustomView and CustomView.xib file. In the xib file each view has a tag. Your .h file would look like:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) UILabel *someTextLabel; //use assign in order to not to override dealloc method

@end

.m
@implementation CustomView

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil];
    [self addSubview:[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0]]; //this object is a CustomView.xib view
    self.someTextLabel = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:5]; //consider you have a UILabel on CustomView.xib that has its tag set to 5
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

This is about how to use .xibs for your custom UIView subclasses. If your app is like a chat then you'll have to add them programmatically.

As for the best way to send messages between two custom views, you'll have to create a weak reference to each other in each of them.

in one

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CustomView *customView;
```

in another

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) AnotherCustomView *anotherCustomView;
```

and just send them messages when some even happens

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
  [customView handleButtonPressedEvent];
}
```

Let me know if this is clear.